Are Americans forbidden from working at Huawei?
Huawei is one of the Chinese companies on the US Entity List, as of November 2024. And there are also "U.S. Persons" rules regulating Americans' interactions with Entity List entities. Does this mean Americans are actually forbidden from working for Huawei? Does this include people who are not American citizens but who received US permanent resident status?
